# Hide data in an azure table from a specific audience

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a resource group in Azure which contains cloud service and a storage account. I want to give access to the resource group to my developers so that they can access the resources and make changes. However, there is one particular table in the storage account which contains sensitive user details. The table is being updated through our client app using SAS tokens.

I want only few selected people from my team to be able to see the complete contents of the table. Is there any way in azure to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Storage access is gated by its account name+key. Anyone with access to that key has access to any object(s) within a storage account, whether, blob, queue, or (in your case) table.

If developers have access to the resource group, and the resource group contains the storage account, then those developers have full access to the storage account contents.

If you wanted to prevent your developers from accessing storage, this storage account would need to reside within another resource group (which the developer does *not* have access to). And then you would have the choice to provide the developer(s) with the storage account+key, or with a SAS to a particular table.

**However:** If a developer has been granted co-admin permissions to the Azure subscription itself, then they have access to 100% of resources within the subscription, regardless of resource group or SAS.

Comment: `If you wanted to prevent your developers from accessing storage, this storage account would need to reside within another resource group (which the developer does not have access to).` -- David, I believe with setting the permissions creatively, once can achieve this in one resource group itself. Essentially all developers are given `Reader` access on the resource group itself and then setting roles on a need basis on individual resources can do the trick. It's somewhat more complicated to implement but is certainly achievable.

Comment: @David If I give my developers the account name + key, they will be able to access the entire table data. Then what is the use of putting the storage account in a separate resource group to which they don't have access? I am confused. If I want to hide data from the developers, after putting the storage account in a resource group to which developer doesn't have access, should I give him only the SAS or can I give him the account name + key too?

Comment: You give them account name+key, they can see everything as mentioned by David. You can't restrict access to specific resources in that account in this case. Better strategy would be to give them a SAS URL with appropriate permissions.