# Restrict from downloading file on Azure Blob

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I'm using a azure blob to store the excel files processed in my application. There is a page on which a link (@Html.ActionLink) is given for each processed excel file. If I put entire Uri for that file from blob, it gets downloaded for any un-authenticated user( as this is public). I want to restrict this operation. I can set its access Level to "No Public Access", however by doing this- my application will get an error (resource not found.)
Please suggest me to ways to handle this scenario.

Comment: This has been covered in numerous questions, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37025776/272109) - just look for *Shared Access Signature* or *SAS*.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for help
I got the solution for this problem. I had seen your SAS post earlier and I did not mention that in problem statement since we were not going to use it. 
Coming to the solution- anyone with Account Key and value can access blob url programmatically to download the file (blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream). Also, we have to set access level to "No Public Access"

Comment: Wait - your solution is to give out the account name and account key??? Once you give out the account key, you've given up all control of the storage account.

Comment: No. Its not. We as developers have account name and key which configurable. So, we set "No Public Access" for blob, then we write a code to fetch a file from blob using 
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobFolder);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
I can post the solution