# How can I restrict users from downloading the blobs into their machines?

Tags: download, azure-blob-storage

I gave access to few of my colleagues on one of my Azure storage Account (Contributor).
The idea is to have them access (read and list) the data in the blob container, but I want to restrict them from downloading the data.

I tried the below:

1. Using SAS key with read and list still allowing them to download the blobs (Using Storage Explorer).
2. Giving them just reader access and "Storage blob data reader" access did not stop them from downloading the data.
3. Changing the blob access tier to "Archive" is not a solution that suites.
4. Tried creating a custom role, but failing to find the exact allow and disallow permissions.

I see the similar kind of question before but wasn't been answered yet # [Restrict from downloading file on Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159912/restrict-from-downloading-file-on-azure-blob)

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has `read` permission on a blob (either through SAS Token or Azure AD role), they will be able to download the blob.

To prevent users from downloading a blob, remove read permissions on the blob for the users. For example if you are using a SAS Token, simply use `List` permissions there. Then the users will be able to see the list of the blobs but will not be able to download it.